# How to add Person to ContactType?

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

I have an array of multiple contactTypes with the same telephone number, like this:

```
"contactPoint": {
    "@type": "ContactPoint",
    "areaServed": "DE",
    "contactType": [
        "Kundenservice",
        "Anfragen"
    ],
    "telephone": "+1111111"
}
```

Now I want to add a person to each contactType. Trying do it on this way:

```
"contactPoint": {
    "@type": "ContactPoint",
    "areaServed": "DE",
    "contactType": [
        "Kundenservice": {"@type": "Person", "name": "John Q"},
        "Anfragen"
    ],
    "telephone": "+1111111"
}
```

I get no validation. What is the right way to do this?

Comment: Unfortunately, contactType can only be text based. I could not see any obvious way to associate a person with a contactType or contactPoint.  https://schema.org/contactType

Comment: suuspected this. Really pity.